# MySQL SELECT with IF based on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables as defined below.

```
Readings: (_id, value, timestamp, sensorId)
Sensor: (_id)
DeviceSensor: (deviceId, sensorId, timestamp)
```

Each `Reading` has a timestamp of when the data was collected. The `Sensor` is the owner of the `Reading`. `DeviceSensor` contains the relationship between `Device` and `Sensor`, including the timestamp of when the relationship started.

In my architecture, when a `Device` is paired with a `Sensor`, the `Sensor` ignores former `Devices`.

What I need is to query all the `Readings` and associate them with the corresponding `Device` at each time of reading. For example:

```
DeviceSensor = [(1,1,1483527932),(1,2,1507058076)]
Sensor = [(1)]
Readings = [(1,5,1483527932,1),(2,3,1493527932,1),(3,7,1507058076,1)]
```

With this data, my query would return: `[(1,5,1483527932,1),(2,3,1493527932,1),(3,7,1507058076,2)]`. That is, the `Readings` that have `timestamp` between `1483527932` and `1507058076` should return `sensorId = 1` and the `Readings` after `1507058076` should return `sensorId = 2`.

Comment: You need an end timestamp on DeviceSensor. Any chance of modifying the table?

Comment: This would be even simpler if `Readings` had a `sensorId` column.

Comment: @MikeAinOz It is possible, but it would double the table size for "nothing". If it's only way, that is doable.

Comment: @BillKarwin That is not possible because of sensor limitation. That's why I need to make this workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r._id
      ,r.value
      ,r.timestamp
      ,(SELECT max(ds.deviceId) as deviceId
          FROM DeviceSensor as ds
         WHERE ds.timestamp <= r.timestamp
           AND ds.sensorId = r.sensorId
         ORDER BY ds.timestamp DESC
       LIMIT 1) as deviceId
  FROM Readings as r
```

The subselect selects the records from `DeviceSensor` which are for the current sensor of the main select, restricted to those with a pairing up to the reading timestamp. The `LIMIT` together with `ORDER BY ds.timestamp DESC` selects the latest of these.

Comment: I forgot to add the `sensorId` column in the `Readings` table, in a way that your query wouldn't work. But changing the line `AND ds.sensorId = r.sensorId` makes the query return exactly what I expected. Thanks!